# Compare two sets of strings and then return whole strings that are different in Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I'm writing a small API listening program, and I'm trying to figure out when something new has been published.  I've figured out most of it, but I'm having a problem on the last step -- where I want to print out something new.  I can compare the two lists of items as sets and get the set of letters that's in the right answer, but I can't seem to get the actual strings to print.

Here's the code I wrote to compare the two lists (both `new_revised_stuff` and `old_revised_stuff` are lists of strings, like `"Bob likes to eat breakfast at http://bobsburgers.com"` with a few dozen items per list).

```
new_stuff = set(new_revised_stuff) - set(old_revised_stuff).intersection(new_revised_stuff)
```

Which returns:

```
set('b','o','l'...)
```

I can get rid of the 'set' notation by writing:

```
list(new_stuff)
```

But that doesn't really help.  I'd really like it to print out "Bob likes..." if that's a new line.

I've also tried:

```
new_stuff = []
for a in new_revised_stuff:
    for b in old_revised_stuff:
        if a != b:
            ''.join(a)
            new_stuff.append(a)
```

Which results in an actual stack overflow, so it's obviously bad code.

Comment: Considering that you get individual characters in the set `new_stuff`, it appears that `new_revised_stuff` and `old_revised_stuff` are *not* lists of strings, but just strings themselves. Print out those two variables to confirm that they are really lists of strings.

Comment: Calling `''.join(a)` doesn't do anything useful; it just returns a new string, made of the characters in `a`, which you just ignore. You have to store that in some variable or pass it to some function or it's just doing work for nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to join any iterable of single characters into a string, you do that with `''.join(new_stuff)`. For example:

```
>>> new_stuff = ['b','o','l']
>>> ''.join(new_stuff)
'bol'
```

However, there are two problems here, that are inherent in your design:

- Sets only hold unique elements. So, if your string diffs are `"Hello, Bob"`, there's only going to be one `o` and one `l` in the *set* of diffs.
- Sets are arbitrarily ordered. So, if your string diffs are `"Bob likes"`, converting that into a set and then back to a string will get you something like `'k iboeBls'`.

If either of those is a problem (and I suspect they are), you need to rethink your algorithm. You can solve the second one by using an `OrderedSet` (there's a recipe for that in the `collections` docs), but the first one is going to be more of a problem.

So, how *could* you do this?

Well, you don't really need `new_revised_stuff` to be a set; if you iterate over the characters and keep only the ones that aren't in `old_revised_stuff`, as long as `old_revised_stuff` is a set, that's just as efficient as intersecting two sets.

But making `old_revised_stuff` a set will also eliminate any duplicates there, which I don't think you want. What you really want is a "multiset". In Python, the best way to represent that is usually a `Counter`.

So, I think what you want (maybe) is something like this:

```
old_string = ' to eat breakfast at http://bobsburgers.com'
new_string = 'Bob likes to eat breakfast at http://bobsburgers.com'
old_chars = collections.Counter(old_string)
new_chars = []
for ch in new_string:
    if old_chars[ch]:
        old_chars[ch] -= 1
    else:
        new_chars.append(ch)
new_string = ''.join(new_chars)
```

Comment: thanks -- that seems to work pretty well.  out of curiosity, is there a decent way to do this with list comprehension as well?

Comment: @jonsurfs: Well, you could do something like [this](http://pastebin.com/gHYfsarF) I suppose. But generally, if you're mutating something as you go, a list comprehension is misleading, not helpful.